# Wait for application to be minimized

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi

I´ve got a Full Screen app witch launches other app and wait until it has been closed, when it detects that, the first application is launched again full sceen with this source code:

```
Dim LastSlash As Integer = App.LastIndexOf("\")
Dim MyAppPath As String = App.Substring(0, LastSlash)
Dim MyAppName As String = App.Substring(LastSlash, App.Length - LastSlash - 1)
Dim sysFolder As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)
Dim pInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
pInfo.FileName = App
Dim p As Process = Process.Start(pInfo)
p.WaitForInputIdle()
p.WaitForExit()
```

The problem is that if I launched skype by this way, when de user clicks on X to close de windows, the app is never closed, it is minimized to system try... so the first app never brings to full screen again.

does anyone know how can I do that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the sample provided here :

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.EnumDesktopWindows